# Bootable SSD and converting to APFS

Tags: macos, apfs

I boot my iMac from an external SSD, which is a clone of my main HDD, running Mojave. I had no issues before, recently with the Catalina being released I downloaded the update and when I choose my SSD drive I get: ***"this volume is not formatted as APFS"***.

What should I do now? I tried from recovery to convert it, but the option is disabled.

**Is the only way to format it? or is there another way I am not aware of?**

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there was no way to change my SSD to APFS without formating. 
I ended up using "carbon copy cloner" cloned my SSD to internal hard drive, then formatted my SSD to APFS, and cloned everything back to SSD. All good now and I was able to upgrade without trouble.

Comment: "It turns out there was no way to change my SSD to APFS without formating." — How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: From apple forums, and trying to do it myself from recovery, I tried different ways before going to formatting. Your method might work but I can't test it now. Hope it helps someone else who might be going through the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's find out why Disk Utility isn't letting you convert your partition. In the Terminal, use `diskutil list` to determine the device node name for the HFS partition you want to convert (e.g. `disk1s2`) and then use `diskutil apfs convert <device> -dryrun`, e.g. `diskutil apfs convert disk1s2 -dryrun`. If it fails, edit your question, adding the output of that command.

If the dry run succeeds, then actually attempt the conversion with `diskutil apfs convert <device>`, e.g. `diskutil apfs convert disk1s2`. Again, if that fails, edit your question, providing the output.

As with any situation where you're messing with partitions, ensure you have a backup of your data beforehand.